LangChain SQLDatabaseChain Failing
I am creating the database chain using the LangChain SQLDatabaseChain.
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db, verbose=True)

Python Version - 3.11
LangChain Version = 0.3.10
While making the db_chain it's failing with following error
"ValidationError: 1 validation error for LLMChain
llm
  Can't instantiate abstract class BaseLanguageModel with abstract methods 
  agenerate_prompt, apredict, apredict_messages, generate_prompt, invoke, predict, 
  predict_messages (type=type_error)
  enter code here
"

Any help suggestion would be appriciated.

you did not declare the llm which is why it failed.
